# Bounding a cubic form with a quadratic form

Tags: limits, polynomials, quadratic-forms, cubics, upper-lower-bounds

We have a positive definite quadratic form $Q(x,y)$, and we have a sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{z_n}Q(x_n,y_n) = 0$.

We want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^3+\alpha y_n^3}{z_n^{3/2}}=0$, where $\alpha$ is a positive constant.

I've already shown it by setting $Q(x,y)=\epsilon$, using Lagrange multipliers to maximize $g_n(x,y)=\frac{x^3+\alpha y^3}{z_n^{3/2}}$, and obtaining a maximum value of $c\epsilon^{3/2}$ for some positive $c$. I suspect this is inelegant, and I wonder if there's some obvious better way that I'm missing.

I note that, in the calculation described above, I used the specific formula of $Q$, which I have available. I haven't provided it, because I'm looking for a solution that is independent of knowing that formula, because my intuition tells me it's something that should work for all positive definite quadratic forms. I hope there's a coordinate free argument, maybe working in the variables $\frac{x}{\sqrt{z}}$ and $\frac{y}{\sqrt{z}}$?

I'm grateful for any insights anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2):

As $Q$ is positive-definite, there are $m$, $M>0$ with
$$m(x^2+y^2)\le Q(x,y)\le M(x^2+y^2)$$
for all $x$ and $y$. Thus
$$|x_n|^3\le(x_n^2)^{3/2}\le A Q(x_n,y_n)^{3/2}$$
for some constant independent of $n$. Likewise
$$|y_n|^3\le Q(x_n,y_n)^{3/2}.$$
So
$$\left|\frac{x_n^3+\alpha y_n^2}{z_n^{3/2}}\right|
\le A(1+\alpha)\left(
\frac{Q_n(x_n,y_n)}{z_n}\right)^{3/2}\to0.$$

Comment: I expected something looking like this would work. That initial fact, about bounds on positive definite quadratic forms: is that a standard result? I have a hard time finding a good text that covers these things.